# Is it better to return an Option<Vec<_>> or just an empty Vec<_>?

Tags: rust, vector, option-type, idioms

Suppose I am writing a function that takes a bunch of strings and filters out the "bad" ones.

The function then returns some strings, but there is a chance that all the strings are filtered out.

So I am wondering, should I use to `Option` here? I could see it making sense that the function either returns the `None` option variant when all strings are "bad", and it returns the `Some` variant when the strings are "good".

The function signature could look something like this:

```rust
pub fn filter_strings(inputs: Vec<String>) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
    // Todo...
}
```

But is there really any point in making this an `Option`?

Would this just make things unnecessarily more complicated since the consumer kind of needs to now check for the `None` variant and also for the case where it returns `Some` with an empty vector?

Is it simpler and more "idiomatic" in Rust to just return a vector of strings here?

```rust
pub fn filter_strings(inputs: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    // Todo...
}
```

Or is there some advantage to using `Option` here that I am missing?

Comment: Is the distinction between `None` and `Some([])` meaningful? If not, then there's no reason to add `Option`.

Comment: Returning an empty `Vec` will make the implementation and usage of the function easier.

Answer (score 12):

If you're asking if it's acceptable to mindlessly replace returning an empty vector with `None`, don't - just remove the `Option` and return an empty vector. This makes the code that is using the return value a lot easier - they don't have to handle the empty vector specially when there is no reason to. Empty vectors do not allocate any memory from the heap, so there's not even a performance reason.

However, there may be cases where the distinction is useful. `None` may represent "unknown", while `Some(vec![])` may represent "known to be empty". Context is important when designing software.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, it may help to use `Option<Vec>`:

- to follow a style or convention (for example there are already a group of interface functions returning `Option<_>`);
- for the convenience to pass to other interfaces accepting `Option`s;
- to suit for some generics of `Option<T>`;

In other cases, I prefer to return without `Option` as it's simpler, and in most cases you want `None` you can use empty `Vec` instead.